# Object is not null and not undefined. What is better - double inversion `!!` or strict equillity `!==` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Very often we check our objects if they are not null and not undefined. I always use condition `if (obj !== null && obj !== undefined)`. Few days ago my colleague shown me the syntax of double inversion `!!` and now I can use condition `if (!!obj)`. This syntax is less.

I'm not a person who are only learning js, but I have a little interest.

So is there any difference between these two ways of object validation? Performance difference? Semantic difference? Any difference?

Comment: `!!obj` is definitely not the same. It will also be `false` for `0`, the empty string and `NaN`, not only for `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: You rather should use `obj != null` (which is also semantically equivalent to your longer expression)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn’t any particularly good reason to ever use `if (!!obj)`, as it’s equivalent to `if (obj)`. `!!obj` and `obj !== null && obj !== undefined` do *different things*, though, and you should use whichever’s most appropriate.

- `obj !== null && obj !== undefined` (surprise, surprise) results in `false` for `null` and `undefined`.
- `!!obj` results in `false` for anything falsy, including `null`, `undefined`, `''`, `0`, `NaN`, and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`!!foo` is used to force coerce a value into its Boolean value. This is, in my experience, often used in APIs that want to return a Boolean value for a value that contains sensitive data. For example, to return whether or not a password is entered you might say `return !!password` rather than `return password`.

Continuing on that, `if (!!obj)` is not the same as `if (obj !== null && obj !== undefined)` for many values you can think of! Such as `false`.